# publish cxf webservice in localhost

Tags: web-services, cxf

used cxf framework for webservice. It works. 
however the webservice is always published in public ip and I see followin in colsole
Setting the server's publish address to be soap.udp://239.255.255.250:3702

how to change that to localhost.
appreciate any help.

Thanks,
raen

Answer (score 0):

That's the WS-Discovery service that runs along side your other services to allow for discovery of the services on the network.   See http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-discovery.html

You can remove the WS-Discovery jars from the classpath and this would be disabled.